# Why Won't this Output 100%

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a progress bar, but I am trying to figure out the percentage. I have two textboxes **Make sure to put the larger number in the second** and it will calculate the percentage by dividing

```js
$("#btn").click(function () {
  var num1 = $("#textbox1").val();
  var num2 = $("#textbox2").val();

  var perectageTotal = (num1 / num2) * 100;

  let totalString = perectageTotal.toString().length;

  if (totalString > 2) {
    var result = perectageTotal.toString().slice(0, 2);
  } else if ((totalString = 1)) {
    var result = "100";
  } else {
    var result = perectageTotal.toString().slice(0, 4);
  }
  console.log(parseInt(result));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox1" id="textbox1" placeholder="Enter Number 1" />
<input type="textbox2" id="textbox2" placeholder="Enter Number 2" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btn" />
```

them, it works but dividing the same number to get 100% does not work, it only output 10. Why?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the whole if statement block at the end?

Comment: Looks like you are slicing off the end of your string so you only get the first 2 characters of 100%

Comment: Just use `(num1 / num2).toLocaleString([], { style: "percent" })`. If you want it as a number, without the `%`, just use `Math.round((num1 / num2) * 100)`

Comment: A day goes by and Mozilla have made a drastic/welcome change to their documentation site.

Comment: @Andy I just noticed that too! I really like it

Answer (score 1):

> dividing the same number to get 100% does not work, it only out put 10. Why??

You are slicing off the end here: `var result = perectageTotal.toString().slice(0, 2);`

You can replace that 2 with a 4 to get your expected result.

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  var num1 = $("#textbox1").val();
  var num2 = $("#textbox2").val();

  var perectageTotal = (num1 / num2) * 100;

  let totalString = perectageTotal.toString().length;
  if (totalString > 2) {
    var result = perectageTotal.toString().slice(0, 4);
  } else if ((totalString = 1)) {
    var result = "100";
  } else {
    var result = perectageTotal.toString().slice(0, 4);
  }
  console.log(parseInt(result));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox1" id="textbox1" placeholder="Enter Number 1" />
<input type="textbox2" id="textbox2" placeholder="Enter Number 2" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btn" />
```

The block of logic at the end seems to do nothing. Also [don't use var anymore](https://medium.com/@codingsam/awesome-javascript-no-more-var-working-title-999428999994) and extract your code into a function so you can explain what it does.

You can [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), [Math.ceil](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) or [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) to always round down to the nearest integer, always round up to the nearest integer, or to round to the nearest integer respectively.

```js
function divisionToPercentageString(numerator, denominator) {
  return Math.round(numerator / denominator * 100).toString() + '%';
}

$("#btn").click(function() {
  const num1 = $("#textbox1").val();
  const num2 = $("#textbox2").val();

  const result = divisionToPercentageString(num1, num2);
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox1" id="textbox1" placeholder="Enter Number 1" />
<br />
<input type="textbox2" id="textbox2" placeholder="Enter Number 2" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btn" />
```

Comment: But how could I get rid of the decimal when I divide 2 / 12

Comment: @GianniLombardo Math.floor() Math.round() or Math.ceil() I have updated the answer to include them

Answer (score 0):

In your first if statement

`if (totalString > 2) { var result = perectageTotal.toString().slice(0, 2); }`

'100' has a length of 3 and will therefore fall into this category and only take the first 2 characters.